# Set line height in Html <p> to make the html looks like a office word when <p> has different font sizes

Tags: html, fonts, css

How to set the line height in ONE html tag `<p>`, when this `<p>` have two different font sizes?

If I set the `<p style="line-height:120%">` .... `</p>`, then the whole `<p>` will only have one line height.

But I hope it will behave like the Microsoft Office Word/(and Google Doc). i.e.: different contents with different font sizes will have different line height.

Is it possible for `<p>` to achieve that effect? Or do I have to do this line by line, like Google Doc? Is there any easier way?

Comment: You cannot achieve this unless you use other tags within <p> tag and set the styles explicitly.

Comment: instead of using `line-height`, can you use `padding` or `margin` (top/bottom) ? i mean, are your paragraphs more than one line long ?

Answer (score 12):

Actually, you can achieve this pretty easy. Simply specify the line height as a number:

```
<p style="line-height:1.5">
    <span style="font-size:12pt">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</span><br />
    <span style="font-size:24pt">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</span>
</p>
```

The difference between number and percentage in the context of the line-height CSS property is that the number value is inherited by the descendant elements, but the percentage value is first computed for the current element using its font size and then this computed value is inherited by the descendant elements.

For more information about the line-height property, which indeed is far more complex than it looks like at first glance, I recommend you take a look at [this online presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/maxdesign/line-height).

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `line-height` in pixels instead of percentage. Is [that](http://jsfiddle.net/SjZh8/) what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I found that in my code when I used a ration or percentage for line-height `line-height;1.5;`

My page would scale in such a way that lower case font and upper case font would take up different page heights (I.E. All caps took more room than all lower).  Normally I think this looks better, but I had to go to a fixed height `line-height:24px;` so that I could predict exactly how many pixels each page would take with a given number of lines.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Beaver Builder plugin on a website and the line-height was not working from the Beaver Builder options. So I have used `<p style="line-height:20%"> .... </p>` in each line and then my line-height were decreased and now it is looking good, no more too much space between 2 lines.

How it was looking:
[image]

How it is looking now:
[image]

How I added the codes:
[image]